# Change file allocation unit size without format

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

Is it possible to change a hard drive's file allocation unit size without formatting or at least not lose files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are third party partition managers that allow you to change the cluster size without reformatting. One example is the [MiniTool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/) (all non-free versions):

[image: screenshot]

Be aware that **all** changes to a partition might corrupt the data. Backing up the important files is always a good idea.

Comment: Acronis Disk Director only changes cluster size for the free space on the volume: http://kb.acronis.com/content/14636.

Comment: And MiniTool Partition Wizard can only [change the cluster size without formatting](http://www.partitionwizard.com/help/change-volume-cluster-size.html) of [dynamic disks, not basic disks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager#Basic_volumes_and_dynamic_volumes).

Comment: I don't think GParted GUI can't do it either; I just booted into it and there is no option to select the allocation unit size (or cluster size) when changing the partition. I read elsewhere that it uses 4096.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch: I based my answer on an eHow article, but GParted doesn't even let you choose the cluster size when creating a partition.

Answer (score -2):

I changed "NTFS", "FAT32" & "ExFat" cluster size without the need to format or data loss with "Mini Tools Partition wizard WINPE".
It's kinda fast. But remember that using mini Tools in PE environment require Paid or pirated version.

Comment: Note: MiniTool Partition Wizard Free Edition does not support this function. To use this function, users need to buy a professional edition or more advanced edition. View Edition Comparison to know more.

Comment: https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/change-volume-cluster-size.html